# jquery Sort nested list by different values (not alphabetically)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to sort a nested list using different variables. So, I have something like the following:

```
<div id="title">
    <h2>AWARDS by TYPE</h2>
    <span>
      <p>Sort by: </p>
      <a href="#" class="sort-by-trophy">Trophy</a>
      <a href="#" class="sort-by-gold">Gold</a>
      <a href="#" class="sort-by-silver">Silver</a>
      <a href="#" class="sort-by-bronze">Bronze</a>
      <a href="#" class="sort-by-other">Other</a>
    </span>
 </div>
```

And the lists:

```
<ul id="accolade-display-list"> 
<li class="accolade-display-list-item"> <img src="/images/us/law/accolades/organisation/27.jpg">
<ul>
  <li class="accolades-org-name"> Argentina Wine Awards </li>
  <li class="accolades-org-details">Silver Medal - 2012, Argentina</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="accolade-display-list-item"> <img src="/images/us/law/accolades/organisation/2.jpg">
<ul>
  <li class="accolades-org-name"> Royal Adelaide Wine Show </li>
  <li class="accolades-org-details">Regional Trophy - 2012, Argentina</li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li class="accolade-display-list-item"> <img src="/images/us/law/accolades/organisation/57.jpg">
<ul>
  <li class="accolades-org-name"> Wines of Chile Awards </li>
  <li class="accolades-org-details"> Blue Gold Medal - 2012, Argentina</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to click, say "trophy" and sort the items with "trophy" at the top, then click "gold" and have those items together at the top, etc. There are currently one of each in my example, but there may be several "gold" items, "silver" items, and so on. I've tried a number of methods, but I have at the most been able to get the list to sort alphabetically, which is not what I need.
These are coming in from a JSP and I may be able to add additional classes to things as appropriate - I can also alter the list structure if necessary. The reason I have the nested lists is simply to make the alignment with the images easier, and because it is possible that there may be an additional line (`<li>`) in the future.

The way I've gotten the list to sort alphabetically, if it helps:

```
$("a.sort-by-trophy").click(function(){
console.log('sort-by-trophy clicked');
var list = $("ul#accolade-display-list");
var desc = false;
list.append(list.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
var aProp = $(a).find(".accolades-org-name").text(),
    bProp = $(b).find(".accolades-org-name").text();
return (aProp > bProp ? 1 : aProp < bProp ? -1 : 0) * (desc ? -1 : 1);
}));
});
```

Anyway, if anyone has any ideas as to something I might try, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use a datagrid like datatables? For Example here: http://datatables.net

Comment: It seems to me a list is [semantically] not appropriate for the single item properties, why did you use that?

Comment: chris, I hadn't considered that - but datatables is just for tables, no?

Comment: Bergi, I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes, datagrid scripts are for tables only, but wouldn't that be nicer in your case? You actually use a list styled as a table, right? ;)

Comment: Hmm...true ;) I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

what i recommend is to have the values you should have, then generate the output (check [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)) and each time you click a sort, then generate it again and replace it.

what i mean, is that you havethe primivitve data:

```
var list = [{name: 'Argentina Wine Awards', medal: 'silver', ... }, {}, ...];
```

then, when is clicked a sort link, you sort the list array by the correct property and generate a new html (using underscore templates) and replace the old html with the new one.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at underscore.js

Comment: So - I've been googling around a bit, and I guess I'd want to dynamically create a template based on whether a given element contains a certain value ("gold", etc) and then inject that template?